# Error: Could not initialize global default settings: Cannot set modulepath settings in puppet.conf

Tags: puppet

I am having trouble setting my modulepath on my puppet master.

```
# puppet -V
4.10.5
```

Here is the default modulepath

```
# puppet config print modulepath
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

I have to add two directories ...

- /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tools
- /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/core

...  to my modulepath.  So I am doing this:

```
# puppet config set modulepath "/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tools:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/core:`puppet config print modulepath`"
```

But I get this error:

```
# puppet config print modulepath
Error: Could not initialize global default settings: Cannot set modulepath settings in puppet.conf
```

The modulepath in my puppet.conf looks ok:

```
# grep modulepath /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
modulepath = /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tools:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/core:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules
```

I am doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Since those two additional modulepaths are specific to your `production` directory environment, try appending them to your `basemodulepath` (from the `puppet.conf`) in your `environment.conf` for `production`: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/config_file_environment.html.

Comment: Thanks. Setting the modulepath in the environment.conf seems to work.  It strange that `puppet config set modulepath ...` doesn't update the environment.conf.

Comment: Want me to write it up as an answer?

Comment: That's up to you. I'd up vote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These extra module paths are specific to your production directory environment, so they can be appended in your production directory environment's `environment.conf` like such:

```
# /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/environment.conf  
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/tools:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/core:$basemodulepath
```

Your `$basemodulepath` is specified in your `puppet.conf`, typically at `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`. It is the value for `basemodulepath` in the INI format. `modulepath` from the config file is not used in the directory environment according to the documentation.

More information about `environment.conf`: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/config_file_environment.html
More information about appending module paths in your directory environment: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/config_file_environment.html#modulepath

Answer (score -1):

lets say you want to list the modules you have installed in your modulepath and would like to write:

```
puppet module list
```

instead of :

> puppet module list --modulepath=C:\tmp\modules

then you could set the modulepath by setting the basemodulepath like this:

> puppet config set basemodulepath "C:\tmp\modules"

This creates a file ***puppet.conf*** inside puppetlabs ; under windows it could be here:

> C:\Users\< username >\.puppetlabs\etc\puppet

you would then afterwards beable to list your installed modules like this:

> puppet module list

if you use modulepath and not basemodulepath then puppet will try to set modulepath everytime causing your error